# Top Visual Studio Debugging Tools/Features

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Which debugging feature of the Visual Studio IDE do you use the most. I agree that it depends on the scenario. But it turns out that people tend to use some features very often (eg Stacktrace) and some very rarely.

Comment: survey - should be community wiki

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from breakpoints and step in/out and run to cursor, I mainly use (auto)watches, stack trace, and the watch under mouse pointer. I think I use the latter the most.

For a "hidden" feature, I'd vote for **debugger visualizers**. Once I wrote an application that heavily manipulated bitmaps. I had some trouble, and wrote a visualizer to display the bitmaps in the memory and zoom on them. It was extremely useful (and easy to write).

Another useful thing is **conditional breakpoints**. I can't recall the exact situation, but I remember I was happy to find out how versatile they are.

And, of course, **edit-and-run** without recompilation is very nice.

Answer (score 3):

Watch

Locals

In Visual Studio 2010 you can expect

[Historical Debugger](http://blogs.msdn.com/ianhu/archive/2009/05/13/historical-debugging-in-visual-studio-team-system-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Immediate window. It allows you to call code, query and change properties.

Comment: In my opinion, this is the single most important debugging helper.

Answer (score 2):

> Run to cursor

Answer (score 2):

"Attach to process..." is very handy

also watch, breakpoints, step into member.

less known: [DebuggerStepThroughAttribute]. It causes VS debugger to skip method or property when doing step into member.

Answer (score 1):

Together with [this library](http://www.templog.org), I use the output window a lot. It's nice to be able to double-click on any log output and be taken straight to the line that produced it.

Other than that, the Autos window, breakpoints, Step In and Step Out (SHIFT+F11). And I quite often use the Disassemby and the Register windows.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudoregisters, not necessarily "top", but handy. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159888/how-to-execute-getlasterror-while-debugging-in-visual-studio/160024#160024).

Answer (score 0):

step into, step over, quick watch, debug.Assert